# UITextView refresh very slowly

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I wrote a function to show the midi event.
MIDI input device send a note every 25ms.
The uitextview refresh very very slowly after my app execute for a while.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
I want to update the UI after got the MIDI event.

Thank you.

```
func MyMIDIReadBlock(packetList: UnsafePointer<MIDIPacketList>, srcConnRefCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Swift.Void {
    let packets = packetList.pointee

    let packet:MIDIPacket = packets.packet

    var ap = UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDIPacket>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    ap.initialize(to:packet)
    var p = ap.pointee
    for _ in 0 ..< packets.numPackets {
        p = ap.pointee
        str_event = handle(p)
        //show_note_event(event:str_event)


        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            //self.current_note_index.text = self.str_event
            self.show_input_event.text.append(self.str_event)  //append string to uitextview
            let range = NSMakeRange(self.show_input_event.text.characters.count - 1, 1)
            self.show_input_event.scrollRangeToVisible(range)

        }
        ap = MIDIPacketNext(ap)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it depends on how long `UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDIPacket>` will take.

Comment: Hmm. I think there's some issue with your for loop, which is forcing a dispatch every iteration it takes. That will be queued and when the dispatch begins a lot of UI calls will be made. Maybe try to gather info in a background thread then dispatch it not that often and see how it behaves.

Comment: Ok, got it.  `func MyMIDIReadBlock`  is executed in background thread.  I want to update UI in `func MyMIDIReadBlock`, does anyone know how to do this?   Thanks.